# How to make a external GraphQL API request?

Tags: graphql, api

I want to query some data from another domain. I dont want to to do it in JS (client side) because I want the content right in place on the page.

I tried with several options and variations with the fetch plugin:

```
{% set poi_query %}"query GetPoi($id: ID!) {

account(name: "Account 1") {
    id
    poi(id: $id) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}"
{% endset %}

{% set client = {
  base_uri : 'https://www.mydomain.com'
} %}

{% set options = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  query: poi_query|json_encode,
  variables: {
    id: craft.app.request.getSegment(3)
  }|json_encode
} %}

{% set results = fetch(client, 'POST', '/graphql?locale=de', options) %}

{{ d(client, 'POST', '', options) }}
{{ d(results.body ?? results) }}
```

It always returns 400 errors, or Missing Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this ourselves last week when we wanted to query an existing, external GraphQL API from inside a CraftCMS website in Twig without using a GraphQL client. I assume that `fetch()` in your code is the [Fetch plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/fetch) for CraftCMS.

**tldr; Try requesting with the raw query, without any filters or quotes, but group `query` and `variables` under `json` key inside `options`.**

This should work:

```twig
{# 1: block-set query without special treatment #}
{% set graphQLQuery %}
query GetPoi($id: ID!) {
account(name: "Account 1") {
    id
    poi(id: $id) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
{% endset %}

{% set client = {
  base_uri : 'https://www.mydomain.com'
} %}

{# 2: query and variables under json key #}
{# 3: no filters for query #}
{% set options = {
  json: {
    query: graphQLQuery,
    variables: {
      id: craft.app.request.getSegment(3)
    }
  }
} %}

{% set results = fetch(client, 'POST', '/graphql?locale=de', options) %}

{{ d(results.body ?? results) }}
```

Three important points:

1. When defining the query, get rid of the surrounding quotes.
2. Group your `query` and `variables` under a `json` key which will hold your request body.
3. Using `|json_encode` or other filters on the query looks like the right way because it’s working like that in JS, where you wrap the whole body in `JSON.stringify()`. But for some reason, this doesn’t return data in Craft/Twig. We got several types of errors instead: `Unexpected end of document`, `No query string was present`, and `400 Bad request`, depending on what we used….

The code above worked for our API after a lot of trial and error, and is rather easy to maintain because changing the query can be copy and pasted from GraphiQL or other sources.

Comment: Hey @jannisborgers , thx for the answer. The "json" option is new to me. It works now! Thank you for the help